# A safer PDO::prepare?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

Using `PDO::prepare` potentially greatly reduces the possibility of SQL injection, because it allows parameterized queries. However, as it also allows non-parameterized queries, its safety depends entirely on how it's used.

For my fairly inexperienced programming team, I'm thinking of putting a wrapper over `PDO::prepare` that has one additional level of filtering: It generates an error if the argument contains any single or double quotes.

Now, during code inspection, all we have to do is check that every query uses the wrapper instead of `PDO::prepare` (or any other function that does queries). When we discover a violation, it either needs to be fixed, or, in very rare cases, it involves a dynamic query that can't be handled by a parameter, such as a variable column or table name. (Very unusual in the kinds of applications we build.) Those few cases can then be studied very carefully to make sure they're safe.

My question is this: Does ruling out quotes in the statement prevent SQL injection from non-parameterized queries, as I'm assuming it does, and is it a practical tool to make code inspections more reliable and efficient?

Comment: Why don't you just threaten to fire them. Post a sign by the water cooler

Comment: *"It generates an error if the argument contains any single or double quotes"* - Be careful, as those can be considered as valid characters for certain queries.

Comment: So you want to preclude Users entering their surname when their name is `John O'Brien` or from quoting text in free-format message fields (`and then I said "Hello"`).... your extra layer isn't doing anything to help security, because prepared statement already does this for you when you're properly binding to it; but it does preclude a lot of 100% valid user interaction

Comment: And instead of teaching your team how to do things normally using parameterised statements, you're forcing them to use your non-standard wrapper instead.... they're not learning how to do things correctly at all; and they could just as easily make a mistake and not use your wrapper as they could make a mistake with bind variables.... code inspections/review would just as easily pick up errors in parameterised statement with PDO

Comment: Do code reviews instead!

Comment: This might be a stop-gap measure at best. While it eschews people from interpolationg string literals, it won't prevent them from inserting numeric literals - which is far more likely to happen casually. And detecting those as well and throwing a warning (don't go the error/exception route) is likely overkill already. And yes, like Mark said, unless it adds any form of convenience (e.g. array/list binding) it will be eschewed.

Comment: You'd be better off building a class or function that forces your team to just put in the parameters and then you make sure it's always in the form of a parameterized query. Eliminating any ' or " is ridiculous.

Comment: Martavis: Can you sketch for me how you would build a class or function that forces the use of parameters? That is in fact what I am trying to do.

Comment: Mark comment #1 and Fred: There's no problem with quotes in data, as all of the proper code would use parameters. My filtering wrapper does not see the values of parameters.

Comment: Drew: (assuming your comment is serious): You could fire them, but that would be after the code inspection. My question is about making code inspections more efficient. The threat of firing by itself wouldn't prevent SQL injection.

Comment: hjpotter92: You are recommending code reviews instead of code inspections, which is what I had in my post. Is there some difference between them that I don't understand?

Comment: @MarcRochkind you have 2.5K rep. By now you know that we only get pinged with an `@` sign in front of our names. So none of the above people have any idea you are responding to them. btw my first comment was a was a joke.

Comment: @Drew: Never knew that. Thanks! I thought your comment was a joke, except that I've heard that same idea as a non-joke.

Comment: Let's say you ask a question, and only 1 unique person comments. And you go back and forth with no one else interrupting it. Then you don't need an `@` sign. They get notified. The second someone else comes into commenting, an `@` sign is needed otherwise they never know

Comment: You can't cure lack of knowledge with some witty programming, no matter how smart you are or how good your would-be-wrapper is. Also, what @Drew wrote is what I'd really do, minus the water cooler. If you are doing work for someone who paid you, it's your responsibility to perform it as safe and good as possible. That's why we programmers exist. If your programmer can't learn how to do something as basic as perform safe queries - that's just negligent. I'd offer learning and if they fail / won't do it - bid that person farewell.

Comment: @N.B., I hear what you're saying, but it's a responsibility of management to give the team the resources they need to be successful. That includes training for writing safe queries. It also includes supporting a process that supports quality coding. Programmers need peer reviews and enough time to write code correctly. Some software engineering failures occur not because the programmers are negligent, but because they have to cut corners to satisfy unrealistic deadlines.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not a practical solution. There are legitimate reasons to use quotes in SQL statements, because string literals and date literals use quotes. There is no valid reason to use query parameters for *every* string or date constant in an SQL query. It just makes your queries unreadable, and in some cases has a  performance cost.

There are also opportunities for SQL injection that have nothing to do with quotes. Any part of dynamic content (i.e. application variables) that is formed into an SQL query has a potential for being insecure if implemented without good practices.

A numeric constant in SQL does not need quotes. Your filter function wouldn't catch these cases.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = $UnsafeVariable";
```

I spoke with a PHP security expert and author, and he claimed there are no cases where query parameters aren't the solution. I showed him this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY $SomeColumn $AscOrDesc";
```

It's a pretty clear example of something you'd like to do in a web application, when you have a user interface that allows the user to choose column by which to sort, or click on an up-arrow or down-arrow to choose the direction of sorting. These are cases that don't involve quotes, and can't be parameterized with prepared statements, but they're still at risk of SQL injection flaws if `$SomeColumn` or `$AscOrDesc` contain unvalidated content.

Nor is it practical to make blanket rules like the one you describe. There are always exception cases. You'll spend too much time reviewing these cases and authorizing developers to bypass your filtering function. The problem with one-size-fits-all rules is that they don't.

**Code reviews are a cost-effective and practical way to improve code quality.**

The better solution is to allow developers to write code in the most practical way, but create a policy that *every* code commit goes through code review.

We do that in my current company. Even senior developers are required to get another developer to do a code review with them. We use github, and we've started a practice that every nontrivial code change follows these steps:

1. Create a branch from the main development branch.
2. Develop the fix in that branch, committing as many times as needed.
3. The committer issues a pull request. This merges all the commits into one diff that is easily reviewed.
4. A peer performs a code review on the pull request. They can use github to comment on the pull request to ask questions or suggest corrections. This creates a log that the code review happened.
5. The committer makes fixes in response to the code review.
6. The code reviewer does a final review and then approves the pull request, merging the fix into the main branch. The temporary branch can be deleted.

Not only does this catch mistakes (even senior developers can miss something), but showing more code to the junior developers will only improve their skills. That creates a *multiplier effect* as your junior developers grow, because they make fewer rookie mistakes, and they can even become senior developers to help the next group of juniors.

Answer (score 1):

> Does ruling out quotes in the statement prevent SQL injection?

## NO

Recently I wrote an article, which, beside other things that you should be aware of, contains a working example of SQL injection that **[doesn't involve a single quote](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example#escaping)** at all:

```
<form method=POST>
<input type=hidden name="name=(SELECT password from admins)WHERE`id`=1#" value="">
<input type=hidden name="name" value="Joe">
<input type=hidden name="id" value="1">
<input type=submit>
</form>
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'root', '');
    $params = [];
    $setStr = "";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($key != "id")
        {
            $setStr .= addslashes($key)." = :".$key.",";
        }
        $params[$key] = $value;

    }
    $setStr = rtrim($setStr, ",");
    $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET $setStr WHERE id = :id")->execute($params);
    var_dump("UPDATE users SET $setStr WHERE id = :id", $_POST);
}
```

> is it a practical tool to make code inspections more reliable and efficient?

Not a slightest.

1. Imagine one were used on this very site. You would be just **unable to post your question!** Which proves this approach unreliable.
2. As it was shown above, quotes are not necessary for the injection
3. It's impossible to create a tool that is 100% fool-proof. You have to invest in your team, not awkward tools.

Comment: @'Your Common Sense': Your #1 at the end I don't understand. Are you referring to quotes within a SO post? Quotes can be used freely in data that ends up as the value of a parameter in a parameterized query. My proposed wrapper doesn't see the values--it is a wrapper only on the PDO::prepare function.

Comment: @MarcRochkind on one hand, I misunderstood you, thinking of the quotes in the data. On the other hand, still there could be no quotes in the query even if you are using a variable in it.